# Spring - jdbcTemplate failed to get Pair object

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

Can I get Pair as an output for `jdbcTemplate`? I tried the following (which work for separate Integers)

```
Pair<Integer, Integer> result = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(GET_PAIR, new Object[]{}, Pair.class);
```

But it returns exception

```
org.springframework.jdbc.IncorrectResultSetColumnCountException: Incorrect column count: expected 1, actual 2
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.SingleColumnRowMapper.mapRow(SingleColumnRowMapper.java:92)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:703)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:639)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:690)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:722)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:732)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:800)
```

Tried with `org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair`

Comment: No results? It doesn't cause an exception?

Comment: You have no results, no nothing to match. Your query apparently yields no results.

Comment: @M.Deinum updated, there's an exception

Comment: The default `queryForObject` method, will only return a single result. Meaning 1 row with 1 column. If it is more complex you need to map the rsult yourself using a `RowMapper`.

Comment: No, `JdcbTemplate` doesn't know that `Pair` is a pair of values. It therefore can't map to it (without manual help).

Comment: @Kayaman so RowMapper is a must?

Comment: @user7294900 any of the mapping mechanisms provided by JdbcTemplate, yes. It won't try to coerce the results into an object, as it expects a single value which is converted to a known type (such as retrieving a date column as a `LocalDate`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`queryForObject` requires one result and just one result. So when you get `EmptyResultDataAccessException` it means that query for Object didn't find anything.

However I still don't think it will work, even if you get a result. A better way is to use a `RowMapper`.

```
jdbcTemplate.query(GET_PAIR, (rs, i) -> new Pair(rs.getInt(1), rs.getInt(2)))
```

Which will allow you to map the elements to a pair (this will return a list, one for each row).